# Can not sign up to "Super User" with existing Stack Exchange Account?

Tags: support, login, superuser

I have an account in Stack Overflow and several other Stack Exchange sites. Originally, my account was tied to my Facebook account but not anymore.

I am trying to log in/sign up to [Super User](http://superuser.com), but both log in/sign up pages only offer the option to use an existing Google+/Facebook account, or alternatively Wordpress, openID, etc.

Usually, when I sign up to a new Stack Exchange site, I am given the option to use my existing Stack Exchange account, but not with Super User.

I tried accessing the Stack Exchange site, and in my profile page, under "accounts" I can see Super User. However, when I click to go to that site, the top bar shows the "log in" button instead of my name/avatar.

What is going on?

**EDIT:** Of course, there is also the option to enter my e-mail address and password, which I ended up doing, and I could finally log into my (existing) Super User account.

Comment: Yes, definitely looks like the same. Sorry I missed that.

Comment: Just flagged as duplicate of that question. Thanks again.